# Array multiple values to variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I need at little help with a site im making as part of a school project.. 
I have a multiple select form that sends the values as an array.

Now at the page where its posted to, if i use print_r($_POST); to see what i get.

I see that i get [tilbehor] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 19 [2] => 20 )
from the "tilbehor" form field.

Thats all fine. The values i get is 11, 19 and 20. - those are all ID from my database selected in the form.

But i need those ID to select somthing from my database, and echo the reslut where the ID in the datebase = the id's from the array...

Now the code i use for that works, but only if one value is sent from the form field "tilbehor"
Im using this code to the the sent form field into a variable.

$t_id = $_POST['tilbehor']

And this to get it to display the name of everything from the database where the ID is a mach

```html
$query = "SELECT * FROM tilbehor WHERE t_id='$t_id'";
$result = $db->query($query);
$num_rows = $result->num_rows;
 if($num_rows > 2) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "
   &#8729; 1 stk - <b>".$row['tilbehor_navn']."</b><br>
   ";
  }
  } else {
  echo "Der er ikke valgt noget tilbehor";
  }
```

But this won't work as it can only handle 1 value in the WHERE = statment...
I need to know how to get this to work when there is multiple values sent from the array.. :/.. Any ideas?

Comment: Easiest way is to `implode()` your post and use an `IN` operator in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$t_id = $_POST['tilbehor'];
$t_id=implode(',',$t_id);//impload the value with the ',' and used IN operate to get all the value relate this id  (11, 19 and 20)
$query = "SELECT * FROM tilbehor WHERE t_id IN ($t_id)";
//"SELECT * FROM tilbehor WHERE t_id IN (11,19,20)"
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;
        if($num_rows > 2) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "
                &#8729; 1 stk - <b>".$row['tilbehor_navn']."</b><br>
                ";
            }
            } else {
            echo "Der er ikke valgt noget tilbehor";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Join array with comma separator
$ids = implode(',', $_POST['tilbehor']);
// Create the sql statement
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tilbehor WHERE t_id IN($ids)";
// Execute sql here...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
$ids = array('11', '19', '29');

$ids = implode(',', $ids);
$query = "SELECT * FROM tilbehor  WHERE t_id IN ('$ids')";
```